# MVC C# - Oracle Exception when call a Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

Previously I was using VS2012 and running this code in my controller worked great, but after migrated to VS2019 I got the following error when calling my SP.
If I run it directly from PLSQL it works fine without any error but when call it from the controller it shows me the following issue in Entities Db Context .

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<Employee> GETEMP(string sEMPNO)
    {
        var sEMPNOParameter = sEMPNO != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("SEMPNO", sEMPNO) :
            new ObjectParameter("SEMPNO", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Employee>("GETEMP",sEMPNOParameter);
    }
```

> OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 8: PLS-00306: wrong number
> or types of arguments in call to 'CSR_GETEMP' ORA-06550: line 1,
> column 8: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Here is the controller action

```
    public JsonResult GetUserInfo(string sEmpno)
    {
        var modeldata = db.GETEMP(sEmpno);
        
        return new JsonResult { Data = modeldata, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Stored Procedure Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CSR_GETEMP(sEmpno in varchar2,
                                       cCurRef out sys_refcursor) is      
    Begin
      open cCurRef for
        select e.emp_no as empno,
               e.emp_name || ' ' || e.emp_last_name as empName,
               decode(e.email,'def@outlook.com','ND',nvl(e.email, 'ND')) as email,
               nvl(e.department_cd, 'ND') as dept_cd,
               nvl(e.org_name, 'ND') as team,
               nvl(e.mgr_email, 'ND') as mgr_email
          from vi_all_emps e
         where ((e.emp_no = upper(sEmpno)) or
               (upper(e.email) = upper(sEmpno) || '@OUTLOOK.COM'))
           and (status = 'W' or
               nvl(e.retired_date, sysdate + 1) >= trunc(sysdate));
    End;
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

EDIT:

Add Complex Type in Model

[image]

Comment: Check the driver.  Often these ORA exception are due to using 2nd source drivers and not the Oracle Drivers.  Oracle the version of the driver and the database have to be compatible.,  When they are not compatible than you get the ORA errors.  It is best to use the correct Oracle driver for you version of the database.  Also best when using ODBC driver (not generic microsoft).  Check on your PC Administrative Tools ODBC Data Source.

Comment: Well, previously worked with 11.2 and now get 12c but I reinstall the new client and got the same isssue

Comment: See following : https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2068368_1.html

Comment: I've done some research and think I found answer.  It is probably that Oracle fixed a bug where error wasn't previously reported.  You code use to work.  See : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ora-06550-error-message-when-running-stored-procedure-cognos

Comment: Hi, Based on the error message you provided, my initial guess is that your controller is passing a mismatch in the number or type of parameters to the stored procedure than what the stored procedure expects.